# Why is spinner widget in Kivy laggy with many values?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to make the spinner widget lag less in Kivy, when the number of values shown is greater than 10?

Reproducible example of code that causes the lag:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGrid(GridLayout, Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).init(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.rows = 3
        self.name = Spinner(text="Hospital:", values=("Glenfield Hospital", "Leicester Royal Infirmary", "Leicester General Hospital", "Royal Derby Hospital", "Chesterfield Royal Hospital", "Kettering General Hospital", "Northampton General Hospital", "Nottingham City Hospital", "Queen's Medical Centre", "Kings Mill Hospital", "Grantham and District Hospital", "Lincoln County Hospital", "Pilgrim Hospital"))
        self.add_widget(self.name)
        self.submit = Button(text="Hi")
        self.add_widget(self.submit)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Data Science Project"
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

In this section of code, it should be clear that the spinner lags, after you scroll to the bottom and try to scroll back up, so is there a way to get around this, so it doesn't lag in this way?

Comment: I have edited your code formatting and removed unused imports. I did not correct your call to `super` which calls an non-existent method (`init()`). After correcting that error (changing it to `__init__()`), I do not see any lag.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, but even with the code changed, I still experience lag when scrolling to the bottom and then back up the top again, do you experience this as well?

Comment: I see no lag at all. Scrolling to bottom,  back to top, back to bottom, ... no lag.